# The function $f$ is discontinuous but $f\circ f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, continuity

I have thought without a solution. Are there actually examples of a function $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ such that $f$ is discontinuous at every point but $f\circ f$ is continuous?

Answers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: $f(x)=0$ for $x$ irrational and $f(x)=1$ for $x$ rational. Then $f\circ f(x)=1$.

Comment: @ totoro: Please, does it work?

Comment: @ totoro: I've just seen that! Thanks!

Comment: You have an example in front of your nose.

Comment: No what you are looking for but a nice, related concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: @ the_fox: Thank you for the edit!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider
$$
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
x,&x\in\mathbb{Q},\\
-x,&x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
This function yields
$$
f\circ f(x)=x.
$$

**Edit:**

Let me fix the bug. Thanks to @totoro, the above example does not work, because it is continuous at $x=0$.

Considering this, let us make it as follows.
$$
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1/x,&x\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\left\{0\right\},\\
0,&x=0,\\
-1/x,&x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Now this function is everywhere discontinuous, and yields
$$
f\circ f(x)=x.
$$

Comment: This function is continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: @totoro: You are right. So what about the template $1/x$?

Comment: @ hypernova: Thanks for the edit. You have my respect for fixing this! @ totoro and hypernova: Thanks for the eagle eye. You are both good!

Comment: Thank you. And I really appreciate @totoro for the crucial comment. I will keep my mistake as it was, in case it could be helpful here :-)